# Provide Windows Credentials through HttpClient in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

First of all, let me say that I am not used to the `HttpClient` API, REST protocol nor Windows Authentication. It is possible I want to do something definitely impossible.

From a WPF application configured like this (don't know if it is relevent):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

I am writing a call to a REST Web Service through `HttpClient`. I want to provide to the WS the currently logged in user credentials in order to check on the WS side if he can actually call it.

I have read plenty of examples on the internet and I though I just had to provide to the `HttpClient` a `HttpClientHandler` configured like this to do so:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

_client = new HttpClient(handler, true);

var response = await _client.GetAsync(concreteUrl);
```

I also tried a lots of combinations with some other properties I found on the internet:

```
PreAuthenticate = true
Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

But no matter the combinations tried to configure the handler, with fiddler, when I look at the request, the header is desperately empty:

```
GET http://my.domain/url/ HTTP/1.1
Host: my.domain
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In the Auth tab:

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
No Authorization Header is present.
```

The WS is being developed in PHP by the way, and the client is running under .NET 4.5.2.

Is this even possible? Otherwise, how could I authenticate the user on the WS through HttpClient requests?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look at your link asap, but at first glance, I don't think it is the same issue since I am connecting to a REST WS and not a SOAP WS: I am using HttpClient and not a generated SOAP Client.

Comment: right, that question was not related to HttpClient, I'm removing my flag and comment